# Django, filtering according to datetime year in a list

Tags: django

I have a list of years. And I want to filter objects that belong to specific years:

```
begYears = [2012, 2013, 2014]
#dateTime field's name is 'beginning_date'. This code does not work...
works = Work.objects.filter(beginning_date__year__in=begYears)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **definitely** a nicer solution than this (writing a property that renders the year and using that? using the dates() filter?), but I can't think of it right now:

```
works = Work.objects.filter(
     Q(beginning_date__year=2012)|
     Q(beginning_date__year=2013)|
     Q(beginning_date__year=2014)
     )
```

Comment: beginning_date is the name of the dateTime field. So you mean 'beginning_date__date__in' ?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question and the thing I want is smilar to -> works = Work.objects.filter(beginning_date__year__in=begYears)

Comment: Hi ratata, my mistake, I think I made a typo. See my edited answer which should work. Btw, 'beginning_date' is not an optimal variable name.

Comment: yes I have already used that code but it gives error... Unsupported lookup 'year' for DateField or join on the field not permitted

Comment: See what you mean, I have added another *ugly* alternative.

Comment: Yes I am using Q in a dynamic way now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.6 doesn't support nested lookups, that is year__in isn't possible. In 1.7 nested lookups are supported, but year__in isn't implemented in 1.7. It is likely addition to 1.8.  For now the Q-approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime generation of the filter criteria (begYears may not be hard coded, but deducted in real life):

```
begYears = [2012, 2013, 2014]
q = Q()
for begYear in begYears:
    q.add(Q(beginning_date__year=begYear), Q.OR)
works = Work.objects.filter(q)
```